# How exactly mysql_connect would be vulnerable after removing support

Tags: mysqli, dbo

Official website is suggesting to use mysqli or dbo as support for mysql_connect is to be removed. But what effect would is cause? What about all the webpages already coded in mysql_connect. Will it make site more vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually support but function itself will be removed (in a distant future).

So, all the webpages already coded in mysql_connect will just stop working. I wouldn't say that it will make site more vulnerable though.

However, to meet such a condition, you will need 2 things

- have mysql_connect actually removed from PHP (which is not even proposed yet)
- have such a PHP version installed on your server.

Which will actually take at least 5-6 years to happen

Comment: @user2207792: `mysql*` functions are _already_ vulnerable.  The point is to make sure that new code doesn't use them.

Comment: @user2207792 this is obviously not true. nothing vulnerable in mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no affect unless you upgrade to a version that have removed those functions. Currently version 5.5.9 has mysql is disabled by default but can still be enabled. This doesn't mean that you can't upgrade if you wanted to, you can still use this wrapper I created using PDO as a backend that would just work as good (check the readme for more info):

on phpclasses.org:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8221-PHP-Access-MySQL-databases-using-PDO-wrapper-functions.html

on github:
https://github.com/AzizSaleh/mysql

mysql extension wasn't deprecated because of "whim" but rather the lack of support for many standard functionality like:

- Stored Procedures (can’t handle multiple result sets)
- Prepared Statements
- Encryption (SSL)
- Compression
- Full Charset support
- Security

For such reasons, if your codebase is small or starting a new project, I would advise you use PDO or MySQLI instead.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You wrote a class which methods are named after mysql ext counterparts?

Comment: ah, there are also functions mapped. But for some reason you made $link variable required. It makes whole idea unusable. Dunno why you didn't make it optional, using default connection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Common Sense: Your first question, yes, they are mapped to PDO functionality that produce the same results as those of mysql_* functions. Good catch on the $link being required, I totally missed that part since that file wasn't included in my unit test. I have updated it so that it is not required, in the actual object it is not required, so I only updated the function mapping. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed as specified in the mysql_* docs.